# Deep Frying Funnel Cakes

Tags: oil, deep-frying

I bought my daughter a "commercial" small deep fryer with a basket and she has been trying to perfect her making of these; however, no matter what type of recipe she uses, the funnel cake batter falls to the bottom of the fryer and sticks to the basket, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the recipe(s) she is using/has tried?

Comment: She has tried Carnival King Funnel Cake Mix but I can't find the ingredients, it is from www.carnivalkingsupplies.com, I'll send you a couple other recipes shortly

Comment: 2 eggs, 2 cups bisquick 1 cup milk and a dash of vanilla and pinch of sugar, that is one

Comment: Next one was 2 eggs, 1 cup milk, 1 cup water, 1/2 t vanilla, 3 cups flour , 1/4 cup sugar, 3 t baking powder, 1/4 t salt

Comment: You should add these comments to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change out the milk for [buttermilk](http://www.marthastewart.com/1151475/buttermilk-funnel-cakes) OR the baking powder for [baking soda](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/paula-deen/funnel-cakes-recipe-1947494). Either of which will improve will improve the ability of the batter to form air pockets, thus becoming more buoyant, once in contact with the oil, thereby causing the cake to rise to the surface.

You would probably also get better results by removing the baskets altogether and using a spider to scoop the finished funnel cakes out of the oil. This should stop the problem of the batter clinging to the submerged baskets.

Comment: thank you, I will tell her, unfortunately she can't remove the basket because the heating elements are not covered.  But we will try the buttermilk and/or soda

Answer (score 0):

Might you be able to get a different basket/an addition to your basket, for a smooth(er) bottomed surface?  A solid-er basket with holes or slots for draining, or else a plate insert for the bottom?

The problem with the basket isn't just that the food touches it, but that the batter deforms around the wires and when it fries, the wires are running through the funnel cake.  The batter may touch the bottom of a smoother container, but it should dislodge quite easily when the batter is cooked because it's harder to hold on to a smooth surface.

At least, that's how it works when we're frying at home (stovetop).  Whatever we're frying can touch or even stick to the bottom or sides of the pot, but it releases on its own or is easily dislodged with a skimmer.

You might be able to find something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00062VZOW) or [that](https://www.walmart.com/ip/9-5-Deep-Copper-Square-Chef-Pan-Glass-Lid-Fry-Basket-Steam-Rack-Induction-Base-Set-of-4/105350517?sourceid=csebr036a306bf3251a4f06bed75979f2fe9000&wmlspartner=bizratecom&affcmpid=1166409733&tmode=0000&veh=cse&szredirectid=15011353507080045087110070302008005) - obviously you need one the right size/shape for your fryer.  Or even toss in a simple, thin metal plate on the bottom.  As long as you shake the oil off (sideways) it shouldn't drag up much extra oil and it may help quite a bit to keep your cakes from sticking.

Answer (score 0):

I followed a recipe that come with my 4qt deep fryer. Every time the batter went to the bottom and stuck to the heating rods. I think the best thing to do is use the stove top. Use a big pot, heat your oil up to 375° and using a funnel drop the batter in. I'm not going to use my deep fryer for funnel cakes anymore, too much of a mess.